Why ucx/libucx can not be found by cmake?
I'm compiling https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT-LLM/ from source in a Ubuntu 20.04 docker and encounter such an error:
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:549 (find_package): By not providing "Finducx.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ucx", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ucx" with any of
the following names:

ucxConfig.cmake                                                                                                                                                                                                
ucx-config.cmake

I tried install libucx/ libucx-dev by apt,
apt update
apt install libucx-dev

but the apt gives me:
E: Unable to locate package libucx-dev

So How to install libucx in docker so that cmake could find it?
(My cmake version is 3.22

Frankly speaking Ubuntu 20.04 is slightly outdated. You can backport the package either from the existing Ubuntu packages or from Debian. Here's the documentation on how to create your own backport in a few simple operations.

Focal does not have libucx-dev. Even nobody backported it for Focal in Personal Package Archives on Launchpad. You need to upgrade Ubuntu till Jammy or newer.
